# Barplot from data organised by factors ggplot2 in r

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame with the following structure

```
df <- data.frame(Build = rep(2000:2003, each = 4), 
            Year = rep(2000:2003, each = 4) + 1:4, val = sort(rnorm(16)))
```

I would like to generate a ggplot bar plot for this data frame, using `Build` as x-coordinate and `Year` as y-coordinate, adding a gradient fill for `val`.

I have tried the following

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = Build, y = Year, fill = val)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

But this is what I get

[image]

What I want to see in the y-axis is the range of values that the `Year` variable takes for each value of `Build`, while preserving the color-gradient representation for `value`; instead what I see in the y-axis is a quantity that is not related to what I have in my data frame (sum of the values for `Year`?).

Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: I apologize, my data frame is of the form `df <- data.frame(Build = factor(rep(2000:2003, each = 4)), 
                Year = rep(2000:2003, each = 4) + 1:4, val = sort(rnorm(16)))'

Comment: Maybe you want `ggplot(df, aes(x = Build, y = Year, fill = val, group=Year)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity", position=position_dodge())`?

Comment: Thank you but dodged bars will not do, in my real-world scenario the number of "val" values is large

Comment: I don't get what you want the plot to look like then, sorry. Maybe show a sketch of your desired output?

Comment: I am not clear of your expected result, perhaps something like this?  ggplot(df, aes(x = Build, y = val, fill = Year)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")

Comment: What I expect to see in the y-axis is "2001 - 2002 - 2003 - 2004 - 2005 - 2006 - 2007" (the range of values that `Year` can take); then I should have a set of staggered bars, each corresponding to the values taken by  `Build` in the x-axis. For example, the bar corresponding to `Build = 2000` will cover the years 2001, 2002, 2003 and 2004; the bar corresponding to `Build = 2001` will cover the years 2002, 2003, 2005 and 2005, and so on and so forth. Besides, each of these bars must encode the corresponding values of `val` for each combination of `Build` and `Year` in a color gradient.

Comment: This sounds more like `ggplot(df, aes(x = Build, y = Year, fill = val)) + geom_tile()`

Comment: Smashing! Thank you @Henrik!